# How to access a public Ip address from a box inside security group

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a box b1 on amazon ec2 which has a elastic ip assigned to it. I have a security group s1 for this box b1. I have another security group s2 which is assigned to a box b2 which need to access port on the public ip address of box b1. I have added a rule to s1 security group saying allow port access from s2 security group.

Even though with the above configuration I was not able to access the public ip address port from a box which has security group as s2.

Please let me know how can I solve this

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is make sure that you're actually connecting to the correct IP address and port. It's not uncommon to find that you're accidentally connecting to the wrong machine.

Next, try to identify if the problem is with the source or target instance. I would temporarily change security group s1 to allow all outbound and inbound TCP and UDP to/from 0.0.0.0/0 and then re-test. If you can now connect OK then that's an indication that you have set up s1 incorrectly so you need to fix it.

Ensure that any local firewalls allow the relevant traffic. If this is VPC, then ensure that s2 allows the relevant outbound traffic, especially the high-numbered ephemeral ports. Allow ICMP through s1 and s2, and then test ping from i2 to i1. Ensure that iptables and/or network ACLs are correct on i2. Use traceroute from i1 to i2.

Here is a more detailed article on diagnosing [EC2 connectivity issues](http://alestic.com/2009/08/ec2-connectivity).

Answer (score 0):

You should reference your instances using the Public DNS record.

e.g. if your instance has public IP `203.0.114.185` and private IP `10.1.234.13`, you are given a public DNS name like `ec2-203-0-114-185.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

`ec2-203-0-114-185.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` will resolve to `203.0.114.185` if queried externally, or `10.1.234.13` if queried internally. This will enable your security groups to work as intended.

This will enable you to use an elastic IP as you simply use the Public DNS entry of the elastic IP. Also, having the DNS resolve to the internal IP means that you are not incurring bandwidth charges for your data between instances.

Comment: I got the issue but I don't know how to fix it. When I added a security group it will recognize only internal ip's but when I am using public ip security group is not able to resolve to private ip. Is there a way to do it

Comment: @kishore: No. You must use DNS. Is there any reason you can't use a hostname rather than IP?